# In Ubuntu 18.04.3 Python 3.8 Upgrade

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, python3

How can I upgrade my current python3 version from 3.6.9 to 3.8? I don't want to setup python 3.8 as a separate version. Because I don't want to type python3.8 command rather than python3 every time.

Comment: You don't, not without exploding your system.  However, look at `pyenv` for a solution to set up Python 3.8 in userspace and to designate what version to use locally in your shell for the `python3` call when using the Terminal and such, rather than using the system Python.  This will also protect you from breaking your system's Python shell.  https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that, 3.6 is default Python 3 in Bionic.

If you just want less typing then define shell alias.